# Make Excel formula treat string as regex

Tags: regex, excel, vba

In my Excel workbook, there are a lot of occurrences of `00XX`, where X can be any digit. For instance, `0017` appears frequently. I want to remove all occurrences of `00XX` using the `SUBSTITUTE` function. So far, I have this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(C1,"00[0-9][0-9]","")
```

This is not working though, and I think it is because Excel treats the second string as a literal, instead of a regular expression. Is there a way to make this formula work? I know that some programming languages allow you to add modifiers to a string to change its meaning, but I have not found any such thing yet for Excel.

Comment: use UDF with regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: Yes, and those should not be removed.

Comment: I have edited my solution below in light of this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses no **VBA**

Pick an unused column, say column **K.**

In **K1** enter:

```
="00" & TEXT(ROW()-1,"00")
```

copy this down from **K2** thru **K100**.  This is a list of all possible "undesirable" sub-strings.

With raw data in **A1**, in **B1** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,INDEX(K1:K100,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(A1,"*"&K1:K100&"*"),0)),"")),A1)
```

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

If **A1** contains:

t0078yetryet

**B1** would display:

tyetryet

Comment: This sounds like a quite feasible solution. I'll definitely give it a try when I'm at work tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply take advantage of the fact that the SEARCH function accepts wildcards?

`=REPLACE(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(TEXT(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,99)),"0000"),A1)),4‌​,"")`

Note that neither of the two solutions so far proposed will replace **more than one** occurrence of such substrings **simultaneously** on a given string.

Regards

Comment: =REPLACE(A1,LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(TEXT(ROW(INDEX(A:A,1):INDEX(A:A,99)),"0000"),A1)),4,"")

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the MoreFunc addin (web link seems to be downe
2. `VBA UDF` below, use such as `=CleanString(A1)`

*test*

```
Sub TestDaCode()
MsgBox CleanString("0018 2450 00notme 0017")    
End Sub
```

*udf*

```
Function CleanString(strIn As String) As String
Dim objRegex As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "00\d{2}"
    CleanString = .Replace(strIn, vbNullString)
End With
End Function
```